# Active Storage: Query on Metadata column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have added "latitude, longitude, geo_location_name, image_taken_time" attributes in metadata. So when I analyze it will add this attributes along with height and width.

In my Project i want to fetch those records which have taken time of particular YEAR.

```
require 'exifr/jpeg'
require 'geocoder'

module ActiveStorage
  class Analyzer::ImageAnalyzer < Analyzer
    def metadata
      read_image do |image|
        if rotated_image?(image)
          { width: image.height, height: image.width }
        else
          { width: image.width, height: image.height }
        end.merge(gps_from_exif(image) || {})
      end
    rescue LoadError
      logger.info "Skipping image analysis because the mini_magick gem isn't installed"
      {}
    end

    private

    def gps_from_exif(image)
      return unless image.type == 'JPEG'
      if exif = EXIFR::JPEG.new(image.path).exif
        if gps = exif.fields[:gps]
          result = {
            latitude:  gps.fields[:gps_latitude].to_f,
            longitude: gps.fields[:gps_longitude].to_f,
            altitude:  gps.fields[:gps_altitude].to_f
          }
          result[:image_taken_time] =  exif.date_time_original
          query        = "#{result[:latitude]},#{result[:longitude]}"
          geo_location = Geocoder.search(query).first
          result[:geo_location_name]       = geo_location.address if geo_location.present?
          return result
        end
      end
    rescue EXIFR::MalformedImage, EXIFR::MalformedJPEG
    end
  end
end
```

How to query on metadata field of blob (text datatype)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of years later, but I just did the following for myself. It's just a matter of joining the proper table and performing a serialized hash query on `metadata`:

**Scoped to a specific record**
`record.your_attachment.joins(:blob).where('active_storage_blobs.metadata LIKE ?', '%"your_attribute":"your_value"%')`

**For all attachments**
`ActiveStorage::Attachment.joins(:blob).where('active_storage_blobs.metadata LIKE ?', '%"your_attribute":"your_value"%')`

If you need multiple conditions, you should add further `where` statements.

Comment: Text search on the metadata column is not great, but until ActiveStorage uses a json column type for the metadata, it seems to be the only solution.  `custom_metadata` on the Blob is where a json data type is really needed.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to query on metadata you can add an index to your active storage table

```
class AddSearchToActiveStorageBlobs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_index :active_storage_blobs,
      "(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(\"active_storage_blobs\".\"metadata\"::text, '')))",
      using: :gin,
      name: 'metadata_search_idx'
  end
end
```